# JavaScript one Statement not Working

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am having trouble with the gender check. No matter what I do it always registers true unless I only have it check for one condition. IE: If I enter m or f it does not register. But if I write a condition only checking for the letter m it will work.

```
function Validate()
{
    var name= document.getElementById('name').value;
    var age= document.getElementById('age').value;
    var sex= document.getElementById('sex').value;
    var error ="";
    var check = 0;

    if(name=="")
    {
        check=1;
        error= error +" Please enter a valid name \n";
    }

    if(age>100 || age<1) 
    {
        check=1;
        error= error +" Please enter a valid age \n";
    }

    if(sex != "f" || sex !="m")
    {
        check=1;
        error= error +" Please enter a valid sex \n";
    }

    if (check>0)
    {
        alert(error); 
        check=0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="cartoon.html" method="post" onsubmit="return Validate()">
    <br>
        Name
        <input type="text" placeholder="last name" id="name"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="first name" id="name"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="middle initial"/>
    </br>
    <br>
        Age
        <input type="number" placeholder="Age" id="age"/>
    </br>

    <br>
        sex
        <input type="text" placeholder="Sex" id="sex"/>
    </br>

    <input type="submit" value="login"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Should be `&&` not `||` in that test. Think about it: if sex is "m", then it's not "f"; if "f", then it's not "m".  Thus it's *always* not equal to "m" **or** not equal to "f", even if it's one of those.

Comment: Logic: Because when it is `f` it can not be `m`. Facebook has ~70 genders. ;)

Comment: Ha thank you I cant believe I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
 if(sex != "f" && sex !="m")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(sex != "f" || sex !="m"){
            check=1;
            error= error +" Please enter a valid sex \n";

            }
```

If sex is F first part is false but second is true because sex is not M -> statement is true -> error

Same goes for M input.

you need to make this change:

```
if(sex != "f" && sex !="m"){
            check=1;
            error= error +" Please enter a valid sex \n";

            }
```

It is a boolean logic error

Answer (score 0):

More complex variant

```
if (!(sex == 'm' || sex == 'f')) {
    check = 1;
    error= error + " Please enter a valid sex \n";
}
```